# Item Lock-up Bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason I'm having trouble moving items in my inventory. Instead of just clicking to select, then clicking once again to deselect; I have to click and hold then move it to the appropriate inventory slot and let go of my mouse button. Shift-clicking things won't work either. This occurs for SSP as well as SMP.

At the moment doing anything is kinda of nerve-racking, so help ASAP would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem, and can be solved by turning Touchscreen Mode off in the options menu. If that doesn't work, quit Minecraft and see if it works then.

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks man, don't know how I missed that it was turned on.